# Flutter cannot find symbol (Plugin)

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I am really getting frustrated about Flutter:

```
C:\Users\User\dev\DIR\app-project\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_analytics_pinpoint.AmplifyAnalyticsPinpointPlugin());
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   class AmplifyAnalyticsPinpointPlugin
  location: package com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_analytics_pinpoint
1 error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am really have no clue why this error is poping up since a few days, with no changes made.
I am not using this dependency directly.
Already tried to remove flutter completly from my PC and the project as well. Afterwards I installed flutter freshly, and also cloned the project.

I also tried:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
```

May someone can help me out?

Comment: Have you tried changing versions for your dependencies? I haven't used this plugin in particular but I've experienced a similar error that was fixed by switching versions on my pubspec

Comment: I had the same error when I upgraded Amplify to 1.4.2 . After pinning them at 1.4.0 and running the commands you stated above, all worked again.
`
  amplify_flutter: 1.4.0
  amplify_authenticator: 1.4.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: 1.4.0
`

Answer (score 0):

What the real solution is: IDK!

But I finally fixed it.

Could be `dart pub cache clean`, a deeper command then `dart pub cache repair`.
or the complete deinstallation of Android Studio and flutter, and fresh install of this.